# Using NSFileManager upon clicking a button

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am new to Objective-C. So in the app I want to make there is a button and when you click on the button it should delete a file. But how can I do this with NSFileManager? And how can I say that it happens when you press the button?

---

**Edit:**
I've bought a book yesterday. I just wanted to know some basics. But I have a second question. How can I copy a file with NSFileManager? I've tried:

```
- (IBAction)MoveFileTo:(id)sender {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath: @"/folder/file.rtf" toPath: @"/folder/folder1" error:nil];
}
```

But it did not work.

Comment: I am coding on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIViewController subclass with a .xib file, drop a UIButton on it from the library. Go to your view controller's .h file, drop this code there

```
- (IBAction)doDeleteFile:(id)sender;
```

and this one in your .m file:

```
- (IBAction)doDeleteFile:(id)sender {
  [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:<#path to your file as string #> error:nil];    
}
```

Then go to your .xib file in interface builder, select File's owner and look for doDeleteFile: action, bind it to your UIButton's touchUpInside event and you're good to go.

Anyways try reading some literature before trying to actually code. At least read about interface builder, IBActions and IBOutlets.